# let X and Y be two random variables, they can be any random variables, then it's always true that $E[X + Y] = E[X] + E[Y]$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

I need to tell if this statement is true or false,

> "let X and Y be two random variables, they can be any random variables, then it's always true that $E[X + Y] = E[X] + E[Y]$"

I think it's false, because X and Y can be different, let's say, X = normal distribution, and Y = exponential distribution. I can't sum average of the first and the average of the second, because it doesn't make sense to sum averages of two different random variables.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties (there might be a catch: "whenever the right-hand side is defined", if this is what they want to hear)

Comment: @Dmitry "for any random variables $X, and Y$", here's the problem, I don't understand if they can be different or not

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini: Generally, it's assumed they are distinct random variables, not necessarily independent. (It still works if they aren't—we still have $E(2X) = E(X) + E(X)$.) However, as Dmitry points out, a condition on the equality is that the expectations of both $X$ and $Y$ are defined.

Comment: @Dmitry but, what does it mean that the right hand side must be defined?

Comment: Consider a random variable $X$ with the following distribution: It takes the value $1$ with probability $1/2$, the value $2$ with probability $1/4$, the value $4$ with probability $1/8$, and in general the value $2^{k-1}$ (for positive integer $k$) with probability $1/2^k$. This variable does not have a finite expectation.

Comment: 1) They can be different. What in the phrasing makes you think that they might not be allowed to be different? When you read "for any $a$ and $b$, we have $a+b=b+a$", do you also question if $a$ and $b$ can be different? 2) Let $X$ be a random variable without a finite expectation. Then $E[X-X] = 0$, while $E[X] - E[X]$ is undefined.

Comment: You just need to avoid $\infty - \infty$.